# add hashmap to another

Tags: android, hashmap

i have an static hashmap :

```
private static HashMap<String, byte[]> mDrawables = new HashMap<>();
```

by thread I download an image as a byte[] and i want add this new hashmap to static hashmap.

```
protected void onResult(String srv, HashMap<String, byte[]> drawables) {
      super.onResult(srv, drawables);
      mDrawables.putAll(drawables);
}
```

but every time that invoked **putAll** ,all info on **mDrawables** is cleared .
how could i add new map key, value to static once??

Comment: Do you have duplicate keys?

Comment: HashMap is not thread safe. You must protect it from timing issues.

Comment: @Xvolks ,no each keys is and unique id

Comment: 1- is there any other thread concurrently accessing `mDrawables` ? 2-
 add logs to show size of hashmap before and after adding new entries: `Log.i("HASH","size before = " + mDrawables.size()); mDrawables.putAll(drawables); Log.i("HASH","size after= " + mDrawables.size());` and see what you get in Logcat ,,, even with duplicate keys, they should be **replaced** not deleted. so there is no reason for the hash to be empty, unless it's already empty, or some other thread is consuming/removing entries concurrently

Comment: i have debuged and every time just add 1 map

Answer (score 1):

Well, accordint to JavaDoc:

```
/**
 * Copies all of the mappings from the specified map to this map.
 * These mappings will replace any mappings that this map had for
 * any of the keys currently in the specified map.
 *
 * @param m mappings to be stored in this map
 * @throws NullPointerException if the specified map is null
 */
```

So, the same keys will be replaced. You can use `Map#put()` in a cycle and check it by yourself like this:

```
for (Map.Entry<String, byte[]> entry : drawables.entrySet()) {
    if (mDrawables.containsKey(entry.getKey())) {
        // duplicate key is found
    } else {
        mDrawables.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
    }
}
```

Comment: .your code has expected error ' ; 'in this line `for (Map.Entry<String,byte[]> entry = drawables.entrySet() ) {`

Comment: Sorry, fixed it